# "no matching function" error on boost::regex_search , am I doing it wrong?

Tags: regex, boost

code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::smatch what;
  boost::regex regex("some +", boost::regex::icase);
  std::string mystring = "some     string";
  bool search_result = boost::regex_search(mystring.begin(),mystring.end(), what, regex);
}
```

the error message is lengty, only first lines here:

```
<stdin>: In function 'int main()':
<stdin>:7:88: error: no matching function for call to 'regex_search(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, boost::smatch&, boost::regex&)'
<stdin>:7:88: note: candidates are:
In file included from d:\boost/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:148:0,
                 from d:\boost/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from <stdin>:2:
```

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows more about the problem will answer, but [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ZieHY$3) works.

Comment: I believe that the compiler is telling you that there are two possible ways to generate code from this: (a) calling `boost::regex_search` with `std::string::iterator`s, and (b) calling `boost::regex_search` with `std::string::cnst_iterator`s -- and it has no way to decide which is better.

Answer (score 3):

*Extending my comment above*

The example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) declares variables of type `std::string::const_iterator` explicitly, and then passes them to `boost::regex_search`, so there's no ambiguity. (Same thing that llonesmiz did)

Alternately, if you're using C++11, you could call `cbegin` and `cend` to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Another alternative: `boost::regex_search<std::string::const_iterator>(mystring.begin(),mystring.end(), what, regex);`

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're trying to search for the regex within the entire string; if so, this should work.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
int main() {
  boost::smatch what;
  boost::regex regex("some +", boost::regex::icase);
  std::string mystring = "some     string";
  bool search_result = boost::regex_search(mystring, what, regex);
}
```

And then using the results as required.